# Rails model validation of has_many relationship count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, has-many-through

In my Rails app I have Card and Pack models, and a many to many relationship between them.  I want to validate that a pack is created with exactly 3 cards in it.  The pack is being associated with cards using a checkbox implementation.

**My problem:** When the validation is run, no associations seem to be made. The validation fails and the output printed is "cards count is: 0". Why are there no associations made by the time the validation runs?  (Note: the associates are made correctly when the validation is removed, so the code works, just not the validation)

```
# Pack Model
class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pack_elements
  has_many :cards, :through => :pack_elements
  validate :validate_number_of_cards

  def validate_number_of_cards
    puts "cards count is: " + cards.count
    errors.add(:cards, "A pack must contain exactly 3 cards.") if (cards.count != 3)
  end
end
```

The other models are just as you would expect, but with no validations.  Here is the Packs form, which is displaying all cards, and a checkbox next to each one, and a submit button.  I want to test that exactly three of these boxes are checked, and I'd like the test to be in the model, not in the form.

```
# packs/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@pack) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <% @cards.each do |card| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "pack[card_ids][]", nil %>
      <%= check_box_tag "pack[card_ids][]", card.id, @pack.card_ids.include?(card.id), id: dom_id(card) %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(card), card.description %>
      <hr/>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? As I have similiar one, and can't find an answer.

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa I did solve it, see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the implementation above is that I was using the *count* method, which does a database lookup.  The database isn't saved until the validation passes, so that can never work.  I changed the implementation to:

```
def validate_number_of_cards
  puts "Count shows there are " + cards.count + " cards."  # always returns zero
  puts "Size shows there are " + cards.size + " cards."
  errors.add(:cards, "A pack must contain exactly 3 cards.") if (cards.size != 3)
end
```

which uses the *size* method, which just looks at what's in memory.  That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The validation is in the Pack Model. so the validation is getting triggered when the Pack Model is saved.

You need to handle this validation in the save of the Card model.

Comment: How would I validate how many Cards are in a Pack from the Cards model?  I can't see a way to do that.